# Another object with the same value for property identifier Uris already exists in AAD App Registration

Tags: azure, time, synchronization

We are trying to implement Single-Sign on for our Power Virtual Agent with teams integration.
We have created an App Registration in AAD for that and it is worked.
Now we are trying to create one more App Registration for PPE environment, as part of the configurations, we are trying to update Application ID Uri on App Registration, while we are setting the value it is throwing an error "Failed to update  application property. Error detail: Another object with the same value for property identifier Uris already exists". we tried by disabling and deleting the old App Registration, though the issue is continuing.
Help us to fix this issues

Comment: Have you tried running `Get-AzADApplication | Format-Table` to see what other app registrations are using that IdentifierUri?

Answer (score 4):

You can also delete these through the Azure portal

AAD > app registrations > Deleted applications

Select the app that has that URI associated with it and select 'delete permanently'

Answer (score 3):

If you delete the application registration in the Azure portal, it is actually a kind of "soft-deleted" and it can be [restored](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/restore-azureaddeletedapplication?view=azureadps-2.0). This is why you keep encountering this error.

The solution is that you can try to [permanently delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) the application using MS graph api.

Comment: Can confirm, faced the same issue using Terraform after a release deleted resources based on a conditional flag, then the next release tried to re-create them conditionally. App registration was deleted in previous release, next release still recognised the resource as being available causing the above error. App reg was soft deleted, had to manually permanently delete it.

There is no flag in Terraform feature block to perm delete app reg like for keyvaults.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/features-block